# angular multiple filters for ng-repeat items

Tags: angularjs

I've an ng-repeat list with multiple filters.

```
    <div class="search pull-right">
        <div class="magnify"><img src="img/magnify.png" ng-click="magnify()"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-box" ng-show="showSearch">
        <input type="search" id="searchField" name="" value="" placeholder="Search" class="textfield" ng-model="search.firstName" /> 
    </div>
```

List 1 (attendee.chat is not 0) gets affect by search TextField

```
        <ul class="table-view">      
            <li class="table-view-cell attendee" ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | filter:search | filter:attendee.chat">
                <h2 class="name">{{attendee.firstName}} {{attendee.lastName}}</h2>
                <span class="job">{{attendee.title}}</span>
                <span class="company">{{attendee.company}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

List 2 (attendee.chat is 0) but also gets affect by search TextField

```
<ul class="table-view">      
                <li class="table-view-cell attendee" ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | filter:search | filter:attendee.chat">
                    <h2 class="name">{{attendee.firstName}} {{attendee.lastName}}</h2>
                    <span class="job">{{attendee.title}}</span>
                    <span class="company">{{attendee.company}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

any DRY approach would also be appreciated since I've two similar templates up there. (difference is attendee.chat it can be 0 or any positive number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach 1

To make the markup more DRY, you could create a directive:

```
app.directive('attendeeDetails', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true, // even though this option is deprecated
        scope: {
            attendee: '&' // don't need 2-way binding
        }
        template: '<li class="table-view-cell attendee">' +
            '<h2 class="name">{{attendee().firstName}} {{attendee().lastName}}</h2>' + 
            '<span class="job">{{attendee().title}}</span>' +
            '<span class="company">{{attendee().company}}</span>' +
        '</li>'
     };
 });
```

Then just change your markup to use it:

List 1:

```
<ul class="table-view">      
     <attendee-details attendee="attendee" ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | filter:list1Filter"></attendee-details>
</ul>
```

List 2:

```
<ul class="table-view">      
     <attendee-details attendee="attendee" ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | filter:list2Filter"></attendee-details>
</ul>
```

Then write the two simple filter functions in the controller:

```
$scope.list1Filter = function (attendee) {
    return matchesSearch(attendee) && attendee.chat > 0;
};

$scope.list2Filter = function (attendee) {
    return matchesSearch(attendee) && attendee.chat === 0;
};

function matchesSearch(attendee) {
    return attendee.firstName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.firstName.toLocaleLowerCase()) >= 0;
}
```

(I am using [`.toLocaleLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) instead of [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) because that has become my preference so it will cater for any locale specific cases. Saves me effort if I ever had to port my code to work in Turkey, for instance.)

### Approach 2

You could also use templates together with `ng-include` like so:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/attendee-details.html">
     <h2 class="name">{{attendee.firstName}} {{attendee.lastName}}</h2>
     <span class="job">{{attendee.title}}</span>
     <span class="company">{{attendee.company}}</span>
</script>
```

Then your markup would become as follows:

List 1:

```
<ul class="table-view">      
     <li class="table-view-cell attendee" 
         ng-include="'/attendee-details.html'"
         ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | filter:list1Filter">
     </li>
</ul>
```

List 2:

```
<ul class="table-view">      
     <li class="table-view-cell attendee" 
         ng-include="'/attendee-details.html'"
         ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | filter:list2Filter">
     </li>
</ul>
```

Note the distinct disadvantage with this approach is if you want to create valid HTML markup is that you cannot put the `<li>` inside the template, since the contents of the template will be inserted *inside* the node with `ng-include` on it. Since valid HTML can't have anything inside a `<ul>` other than `<li>`s, you need to duplicate the `<li>` and its classes for both lists.

### Why Not Multiple Filters?

The reason I chose to go with the controller function for the filter, rather than using multiple filters inline in the expression is that your criteria for list 1 of showing all elements with `attendee.chat > 0` is not possible to express using any of the builtin filters as far as I can see. You cannot specify an expression for the thing to match against.

You *could* use multiple filters for List 2, though, since you are only checking for a single value for `attendee.chat` (0).

You could do `ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | filter:{firstName:search.firstName,chat:0}"`, or if you had to have multiple filters instead (which will be slower, so I don't know why you would), you could do `ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | filter:search | filter:{chat:0}"`.

Comment: I like the angular's inline templates, any option with that? also what's the purpose of `toLocaleLowerCase()`

Comment: can you please do a without DRY approach, I wanna see multiple filters applied inline, one for the search field and the other for attendee.chat option